# Is there a name for serving a fully-contained web component over a end-point?

Tags: javascript, web-services, server-side-rendering

Is there a name for serving a fully-contained web component over a end-point?help?
You might of heard of a technique of serving a custom element (or "web component") over an end-point by making the payload a string that contains the raw HTML to represent the web component itself. But that would just cover the HTML, What about the CSS & JS?

[this](https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2d2bb0cdec3f2a16cf519dbaa791ce1b) example gives you an idea of how this might be accomplished. By wrapping the outermost element in a  tag with an IIFE containing an init function inside it that constructs the web component, wires to up with JS and styles it with CSS programmatically, a developer on the client-side can consume this component as a whole from a service, allowing them to simply throw that script tag into the HTML of their document and have the component "magically" appear in their page when the page loads and the  tag is evaluated.

This method contrasts the more simplistic practice of receiving the raw data (perhaps as a JSON object) over an end-point. Developers on the client-side would then construct the web component themselves with their own CSS and JS (events, handles, callbacks, ect).

So is there a name for this practice? Specifically: Is there a name for the practice of serving a fully-contained web component over an end-point?

I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could suggest some examples or best practices of this method that I could reference.

Answer (score 0):

Found it ["Isomorphic Javascript"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphic_JavaScript)